# How do I check if an association exists in ActiveRecord from inside a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, sunspot-solr

I tried all combinations that I could find online and it always fails.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to  :user, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one     :match # educational matches 

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :match
  attr_accessor                 :form

  unless match.present?
    searchable do

      integer :id
      string :country
      string :state
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
Match belongs_to :profile
```

Inside the Profile model I try to do:

```
  unless profile.match.exist? (does profile have a match association existing?) 
    .. do something

  end
```

Comment: You can't do `unless match.present?` at the class level, since you're using no special Profile instance, here. It's not the Profile class that has one match, it's profile instances.

Comment: @OlivierElMekki so any way how to do it then using a lambda perhaps?

Comment: I don't use sunspot myself, but it seems it can handle conditional indexing passing proc [as :if option](http://mikepackdev.com/blog_posts/19-conditional-indexing-with-sunspot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by [the blog post that Olivier linked to](http://mikepackdev.com/blog_posts/19-conditional-indexing-with-sunspot) and [confirmed in the Sunspot documentation](http://outoftime.github.io/sunspot/docs/Sunspot/Rails/Searchable/ActsAsMethods.html#searchable-instance_method), you could do:

```
# In your Profile model
searchable :if => proc { |profile| profile.match.present? } do
  integer :id
  string :country
  string :state
end
```